# Assign jQuery.get() to a variable?

Tags: ajax, jquery, callback

What is the correct way of assigning to a variable the response from jQuery.get() ?

```
var data = jQuery.get("output.csv");
```

I was reading that jQuery.get() must have a callback function? why is that? and how would i use this callback function to assign the response back to the data variable?

Thanks in advance for your help and clarification.

**Update**:

Thank you all for your answers and explanations. I think i am starting to finally grasp what you are all saying.
My code below is doing the right thing only the first iteration of it.
The rest of the iterations its writing to the page undefined.
Am i missing something?

```
<tbody>
<table id="myTable"> 

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $.get('output.csv', function(data) {
                csvFile = jQuery.csv()(data);

                for ( var x = 0; x < csvFile.length; x++ ) {
                    str = "<tr>";
                    for ( var y = 0; y < csvFile.length; y++) {
                        str += "<td>" + csvFile[y][y] + "</td>";
                    }
                    str += "</tr>";
                }
                $('#myTable').append(str);


        });

    </script>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 8):

A callback function is required for asynchronous function calls, like an AJAX GET request.  There is a delay between calling the `get` function and getting a response back, which could be a millisecond or several minutes, so you need to have a callback function that gets called when the asynchronous GET has completed its work.

Here's some more info on jQuery's AJAX `get` function:  http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get#urldatacallbacktype.

From jQuery's examples:

```
// this would call the get function and just 
// move on, doing nothing with the results
$.get("test.php");

// this would return the results of the get
$.get("test.php", function(data){
  alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

If you get `undefined` when you try to use the `data` variable in the callback function, open up the console in Firebug in Firefox and watch the `get` request.  You can see the raw request and the response that it comes back with.  You should get a better indication of the issue after seeing what's being sent to the server and what's being sent back to the client.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a tip to help troubleshoot the data variable being undefined.

Comment: @DCrawmer check what pixeline is saying. if the parse of the get request is taking too much is better to take the data in the callback. actually this is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Actually in your example the data will be the XMLHttpRequest request object.

```
var x;
$.get( 'output.csv', function(data){
    x = data;
    console.log(x); // will give you the contents.
});
```

Comment: Given (to my understanding) that `get` is asynchronous, wouldn't the `log` be printing `undefined` every time?

Comment: yes, this code is giving me undefined every time, how do i prevent that?

Comment: put the console.log() call inside the callback!

Comment: @pixeline is right. if the call takes too long the log is better in callback

Answer (score 4):

tsvanharen answered the question well, but DCrawmer's still missing the point.  Let me attempt a clarification for him.  I'm oversimplifying some of this, and smoothing over some details.

Look at the code shown below.  This is pretty much the same code as tsvanharen's, except that I've replaced the anonymous function for the callback with an actual function pointer, and am a little more explicit so you can see what's going on:

```
var x = null;

function myCallback(data)
{
   alert("Data Loaded:" + data);
}

$.get("test.php", myCallback);

// the rest of your code
alert("The value of X is: " + x);
```

Assuming that test.php takes even a moment or two to load, notice the order that the alerts probably come up in:

```
1. "The value of X is"
2. "Data Loaded"
```

The function `$.get()` runs instantaneously.  JavaScript moves on and runs the rest of your code right away.  In the background, it's retrieving your page at test.php.  jQuery hides some of the messy details of this.

The callback function (the second argument to `$.get()`) runs later (*asynchronously*).  Or, said another way, the function `myCallback` is a handler to an event.  That event is "`$.get()` has finished retrieving the data".  It doesn't get run until that point.  It doesn't run when `$.get()` runs!  `$.get()` just remembers where that function is for later.

The function `myCallback` may run milliseconds or minutes later, long after `$.get()` has been dealt with.

If `myCallback` doesn't run until minutes later, then what's the value of x when the "The value of X" code is run?  It's still `null`.  **There's your bug**.

To use the data retrieved from the page in your script, you have to do things more like this:

1. Start your script, declare your variable to hold the data.
2. Call `$.get()`, with a callback function to handle the return.
3. Do nothing else.  [Or, at least, nothing that requires the data]
     Let the page just sit there.

   ...sometime in the future...

   X. Your callback function will get run, and have the results of your web page.
     Your callback function can:
       * Display the data
       * Assign that data to a variable
       * Call other functions
       * Go along it's merry way.

Comment: thank you very much for the clarification. please see my update to the question and tell me what am i doing wrong? thank you for your help.

Comment: Divide and conquer.  Make sure that the jQuery.get is actually returning the data you think it is.  Put an alert(data) at the beginning of the function to make sure that the data was read from output.csv correctly.  (That's not a well-formed url, are you sure that's what you want?)  Proceed from there.

Answer (score 4):

I really struggled with getting the results of jQuery ajax into my variables at the "document.ready" stage of events.

jQuery's ajax would load into my variables when a user triggered an "onchange" event of a select box after the page had already loaded, but the data would not feed the variables when the page first loaded.

I tried many, many, many different methods, but in the end, the answer I needed was at this stackoverflow page: [JQuery - Storing ajax response into global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905298/jquery-storing-ajax-response-into-global-variable)

Thanks to contributor Charles Guilbert, I am able to get data into my variables, even when my page first loads.

Here's an example of the working script:

```
    jQuery.extend
    (
       {
          getValues: function(url) 
          {
              var result = null;
              $.ajax(
              {
                url: url,
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'html',
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) 
                {
                    result = data;
                }
              });
          return result;
          }
       }
    );

// Option List 1, when "Cats" is selected elsewhere
optList1_Cats += $.getValues("/MyData.aspx?iListNum=1&sVal=cats");

// Option List 1, when "Dogs" is selected elsewhere
optList1_Dogs += $.getValues("/MyData.aspx?iListNum=1&sVal=dogs");

// Option List 2, when "Cats" is selected elsewhere
optList2_Cats += $.getValues("/MyData.aspx?iListNum=2&sVal=cats");

// Option List 2, when "Dogs" is selected elsewhere
optList2_Dogs += $.getValues("/MyData.aspx?iListNum=2&sVal=dogs");
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify the callback function in the parameter to get method. Your data will be in the variable you specify in the function.

```
$.get("output.csv", function(data) {
    // Put your function code here, the 'data' variable will hold your data.
});
```