# set ajax response as global variable

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm currently messing with google's apis using ajax trough jquery library.
In order to use a google service API i need to get an auth token sending a request to ClientLogin. Actually, i've no idea how to pass the token to the second request .

I've set a global variable token as `var token = null;`

I call two requests on `$(document).ready event`.

1. The first one is an https POST
   request to google clientLogin in
   order to get user credential token.

Here's the code of the first ajax request :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://" + host + clientLoginEntryPoint,
    data: cLRequestData(accountType, user, pwd, service),
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (response) {      
        var tokenArray = response.split("="); // Split to response tokenArray[3] is the auth token
        token = tokenArray[3];
        $(".status").html(token);
    }
}); // END OF CLIENT LOGIN REQUEST
```

2. The second one is supposed to call the contacts API with an http GET.

   ```
   $.ajax({
   type:  "GET",
   url: "http://" + host + googleContactEntryPoint,
   beforeSend: function(xhr) {
       xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'GoogleLogin auth=' + token);
       xhr.setRequestHeader('GData-Version', '3.0');
   },
   success: function(response, textStatus, xhr) {
       var names = $(response).find('entry>title').text();
       $(".status").text(names);
   },
   error: function(xhr, status, error) {
       $(".status").html(xhr.status+ "&nbsp;"+ xhr.statusText );
   }
   ```

   }); // END OF GOOGLE CONTACT REQUEST

The problem i'm facing is that token is set to null when i try to set Google Authentification Header in the second request. I've already read [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905298/jquery-storing-ajax-response-into-global-variab) but this is not working for me. I now that must be something to do with callback/events but i'm couldn't figure how to do this.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question was updated:**

<s>You are redeclaring a local variable in your first request named `token`, so it doesn't use the global `token` that you initiated with `null`.</s>

Remove the `var` keyword in the first request.

```
token = tokenArray[3];
```

If the requests run sequentially, then the second will not wait for the first to receive its response before it executes.

If that's the case, place the second request in a `function`, and call that function from the `success:` callback in the first.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://" + host + clientLoginEntryPoint,
    data: cLRequestData(accountType, user, pwd, service),
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (response) {      
        var tokenArray = response.split("="); // Split to response tokenArray[3] is the auth token
        token = tokenArray[3];
        $(".status").html(token);
        // Call second request here
        secondRequest( token );  // optionally pass the "token"
                                 //   instead of using global var
    }
}); // END OF CLIENT LOGIN REQUEST


function secondRequest( token ) {
    $.ajax({
    type:  "GET",
    url: "http://" + host + googleContactEntryPoint,
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'GoogleLogin auth=' + token);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('GData-Version', '3.0');
    },
    success: function(response, textStatus, xhr) {
        var names = $(response).find('entry>title').text();
        $(".status").text(names);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        $(".status").html(xhr.status+ "&nbsp;"+ xhr.statusText );
    }
    })
}
```

*(In this code, you could actually get rid of the global `token` variable, and just pass the `token` from the first request to the second as a function parameter.)*

Comment: Many thanks Patrick for your answer. 
I've updated code but my script broke when i call the secondRequest. 
It break when i'm setting the Authorization header to the token value. I've got the following console error:
Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader]"  nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"  location: "JS frame :: GContactsAPI.js :: anonymous :: line 45"  data: no]

Any ideas ?

Comment: @anchnk - Have you verified that `token` looks correct inside of `secondRequest()`? I don't know anything about the response you're getting from the first request, or how to properly set up your second. I'd do `console.log( token )` in `secondRequest()` function to make sure it has the value you expect.

Comment: Yes i got the same value than in the full response. I'll try to restart browser and see. Another point is that i'm doing that request from a local file from now. So i added netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserRead"); to be able to send request but i'm not sure it have something to do with that.

Comment: @anchnk - I'm just not sure. I guess I'd "Accept" this answer (click the checkmark to the left of it) and start a new question that describes the issue since it a little bit beyond the original question. :o)

Answer (score 0):

looks like the scope of the variable token is not global.  you have it defined in the scope of the success function for the initial ajax request

Comment: Sorry that was an error during copy/pasting i've edited the post to reflect the current version of the source, it isn't working without the var keyword.