# Jquery - Store Ajax jSON response as variable

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, variables

I'm trying to get the result of an ajax request to set in a variable which I can access outside that request. I've tried this [JQuery - Storing ajax response into global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905298/jquery-storing-ajax-response-into-global-variable) but my variable `beer` remains undefined outside the `$.getJSON` and `$.ajax` functions (I tried both).

Here is my code and where I am able to see the results from the `console.log(beer)`.

```
var beer;
$.getJSON(jsonUrl, function (json) {
    beer = json;
    console.log(beer); // returns beer
});
console.log(beer); // returns undefined

var beer = (function () {
    var result;

    $.ajax({
        url: jsonUrl,
        success: function (data) {
            result = data;
            console.log(beer); // returns beer

        }
    });
    console.log(result); // returns undefined
    if (result) return result;
})();
console.log(beer); // returns undefined
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That's an asynchronous request, so it gets fired off, but your script doesn't wait around for a response before it moves on.  If you need to wait on a ajax request to finish, try something like this:

```
var beer;
$.getJSON(jsonUrl,function(json){
    beer = json;   
    checkDrink();                
});         

function checkDrink() {
    console.log(beer);
}
```

Comment: So how can I access beer later in the script from outside the function?

Comment: Anything that depends on the result of that JSON request needs to be in that separate function.

Comment: And why wouldn't this work ?


    beer = $.ajax({
     url: jsonUrl,
     success: function(data) {
      return data;
     }
       });

Comment: "success" is an event on the $.ajax() object.  It doesn't execute that function until it gets a response from the server, which could be 10ms or 10 minutes from the time its executed.  Meanwhile, your main code line keeps executing.

Answer (score 10):

Suggest the code below:

```
var beer = $.ajax({
    url: jsonUrl,
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json'
}).responseJSON;
```

The key moments are:

1. set `async` to false, to return result as variable, not call success callback asynchronious
2. set `dataType` to json to parse server response string as json

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to access the data before it actually comes back from the server, the 'success' function is actually a callback that gets called when the ajax call finishes successfully. The $.ajax (or $.get) functions return inmediatly...

You would need to somehow signal to the interested functions that you got the data into the 'beer' var inside your success callback