# Using jQuery's .load function to load an element from the previous page in a JS variable

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, load

I want to use jQuery's `.load` function to load an element from the previous page into a JavaScript variable.

So instead of

```
var x = document.referrer; 
$('.title').load(x +" #name");
```

I want it to be:

```
var x = document.referrer; 
$('var y').load(x +" #name");
```

so I can work with the variable.

Do you have any suggestions how to manage it?

Comment: i think you can use the $.get() function

Comment: Does not seem like a new question, try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203502/jquery-load-to-variable)!?