# Can't store data fetched with jQuery JSONP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp, store

I'm trying to fetch a bunch of photo data from Flickr via a jQuery AJAX call using JSONP, but I don't want to use the data right away. Instead, I'd like to preserve it for use later. In a complicated case, I'd like to let users perform different queries on the prefetched data. In a simpler case, I'd like to just load the next *n* images each time the user clicks a button.

Right now, I'm testing just the most basic functionality below, which is adapted from the best answer to this question: [JQuery - Storing ajax response into global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905298/jquery-storing-ajax-response-into-global-variable)

However, the retrieved JSON data is not getting stored in the jsonData variable as it should. I put the alert statements to debug, and the strange thing is that the getData() alert is triggered before the alert in the callback function. Why is this happening?

```
var dataStore = ( function() {
  var jsonData;

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      tags: "dog",
      tagmode: "any",
      format: "json"
    },
    success: function(data) {
      jsonData = data;
      alert(jsonData);
    }
  });

  return { getData : function()
  {
      if (jsonData) return jsonData;
      else alert("no data!");
  }};
})();

var stuff = dataStore.getData();

$.each(stuff.items, function(i,item) {
  $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
  if ( i == 3 ) return false;
});
```

Comment: It's best to ask **one** question in each question here on Stack Overflow. In the above, you're asking two quite distinct questions: 1) Why is your code not working as you expect, and separately 2) Should you be doing this or putting in hidden images. Conflating questions reduces the quality of both the question and its answers, best to split them up.

Comment: I see, thanks for the tip. Should I split it up now, after the fact?

Comment: `@stchangg`: I probably would, yeah. Since the other answer here addresses the "why doesn't this code work right" aspect, I'd leave that part here and ask the image best practices question separately. I can copy over the part of my answer that relates to that.

Comment: Cool, just extracted out the other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353733/is-it-better-to-use-the-hidden-css-attribute-or-fetch-each-set-of-new-images

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ...and the strange thing is that the getData() alert is triggered before the alert in the callback function. Why is this happening?

Because ajax calls in general are, by default, *asynchronous* — and JSONP calls are always asynchronous by their nature (other kinds of ajax calls can be made synchronous, but it's generally a bad idea).

This means your

```
var stuff= dataStore.getData();
```

line executes before the JSONP request completes. This is also why it doesn't see anything in `jsonData`.

You need to move any processing of the JSONP call result into something called from the `success` callback of the request.

Comment: Thanks! I wish I could upvote but I don't have enough rep points yet.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `stuff` is `undefined` when `$.each` runs because `stuff` hasn't finished running yet. Everything needs to be in a callback. There's numerous ways to get around it from the most ugly and hacky of doing a `setInterval()` that checks if `stuff === undefined` and if NOT then it does the `$.each` to a more JS native way of just using callbacks.

Personally, I highly suggest you just use callbacks more effectively. Here's what i'd do. This should put you on the right track. Obviously a lot of this is faux code, but can easily be modified to your needs.

```
var cachedImageData = {}; //To check if data exists for the search term

var displayImages = function(stuff){
  $.each(stuff.items, function(i,item) {
    $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
    if ( i == 3 ) return false;
  });
}

$('button').bind('click',function(){ //Triggers the ajax...
  if(cachedImageData[$('input').val()] === undefined){ //If this search doesn't exist...
    $.ajax({
      url:''
      data:{ tag: $('input').val() }, //Get the value however
      success: function(data){
        cachedImageData[$('input').val()] = data; //Save for later
        displayImages(data); //Run the display images function which is your $.each()
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But... where does cachedImageData get added to?

Comment: Updated. You'd save once you got the data.