# Is it better to use the "hidden" CSS attribute or fetch each set of new images?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp, hidden

I'm trying to fetch a bunch of photo data from Flickr via a jQuery AJAX call using JSONP. I'd like to display *n* images at a time, then show the next *n* images each time the user clicks a button.

I've read that one way is to add all the images to the DOM in the callback function and use the "hidden" CSS attribute to hide and reveal the next *n* images as the user clicks. Is this a recommended practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends entirely on what you're trying to do. If you create `img` elements and set their `src`, even if they're hidden via `display: none` (for that matter, even if you don't add them to the DOM at all) the browser will still request the image from the server. If your page allows the user to filter through the images before viewing them, or allows paging, that can generate unnecessary network traffic. Ideally, prefetch images only when it's fairly likely the user will view them — but early enough that the user isn't left waiting for them.

Note that, again, you *don't* have to put the `img` elements in the DOM until you're ready to. Just creating the `img` element and setting its `src` is sufficient ([try it here](http://jsbin.com/emoveb), that code never adds the `img` to the DOM at all). So you could keep a map of the `img` elements, for instance:

```
var preloaded = {};
function preload(path) {
    var img;
    if (!preloaded[path]) {
        preloaded[path] = img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = path;
    }
}
```

Then you have them when you're ready for them, but without having to tuck them away somewhere in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is best to load all the images as early as possible.  This decreases wait time for the user, and they are more likely to view all your content.

You should load the first *n* images, then on the call back load the next *n* (hidden of course), and then on their call back so on and so forth until everything is pre-loaded.

That being said, if you have 100s of sets of size *n*, you should limit the number of pre-loading, maybe only preload the next two or three sets (and every click further should load another set). The idea is to always be ahead of the user so they never have to wait to view the next set of images.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of cascading the loads. Makes sense. By the way, what you're describing is slightly different from the original solution I proposed, which says just preload everything all at once (which would result in a long initial wait time).

Answer (score 0):

it is better achieved by carousel. There was a example of flickr carousel. Check the below link it may be useful for http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/dynamic_flickr_feed.htmlou.