# JSONP Callback Function inside jQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, jsonp, getjson

I'm writing my first jQuery plugin and looking for some help making a JSONP request inside it.

Normally I setup my JSON data inside of a callback function like so

```
saveDataCommunityPartners({
    "newsBlockItems": [
        {
            "title": "title title title",
            "img": "item-img.jpg"
        },
        {
            "title": "title title title",
            "img": "item-img.jpg"
        }
        ... and so on and so forth
    ]
})
```

Then on a page I call `.getJSON()` like so:

```
$.getJSON("http://i.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/.element/media/2.0/teamsites/warriors/json/json-redesign-communitypartners.js?callback=?");
```

And set up the callback function

```
function saveDataCommunityPartners(data) {
    alert("got data");
}
```

And everything works fine. How would I get this to work inside my plugin? If I do it like it is below, I'm getting a "Uncaught ReferenceError: saveDataCommunityPartners is not defined" error.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.createNewsBlock = function( options ) {
        // Establish defaults
        var settings = $.extend({
        thisData        : {},
        pageFilter      : "community"
    }, options);

    $.getJSON("http://i.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/.element/media/2.0/teamsites/warriors/json/json-redesign-communitypartners.js?callback=?");

    function saveDataCommunityPartners(data) {
        alert("got data");
    }
}(jQuery));
```

I can either change the plugin, or how I set up the JSON file itself, whatever is recommended. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working using [**this code from here**](http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "http://i.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/.element/media/2.0/teamsites/warriors/json/json-redesign-communitypartners.js?callback=?",
    async: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'saveDataCommunityPartners',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
        parseJSON(json); // pass to function to use for whatever
    },
    error: function(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
});
```

Note that originally in the success function I tried to store the json in a variable called data like so: `data = json;`, but ran into problems as this does not ensure that the json will have returned by the time `data` could be accessed. See [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353374/cant-store-data-fetched-with-jquery-jsonp) for more info on that end.

Answer (score 1):

The getJSON method has a callback feature that you can use.

```
$.getJSON("http://i.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/.element/media/2.0/teamsites/warriors/json/json-redesign-communitypartners.js?callback=?",function(data){

saveDataCommunityPartners(data);

});
```

OR use the chained command

```
$.getJSON("http://i.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/.element/media/2.0/teamsites/warriors/json/json-redesign-communitypartners.js?callback=?").done(function( data ) {

saveDataCommunityPartners(data);

})
```

You can also relocate the saveDataCommunityPartners function outside the JQuery container if the error still persists.

Comment: hm neither of those seem to be working (getting the same error). I basically just need to store the data in a variable. and I need to do this inside the jQuery container because the plugin needs to parse through the data to find some things