# How to add string from database to variable

Tags: jquery

I have some data from DB then I need to load. Something like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "something.aspx",
    data: "{ 'something': 'something'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(res) {}
});​
```

I want returning string res.d to be added to var a, how this can be achieved.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var a =
});
```

Basically I am using xDHTML schedule unit view. Schedule units needs to be loaded on page load. So how to ad string from DB to var

Comment: what does your .net code look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var a = null;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "something.aspx",
        data: "{ 'something': 'something'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(res) {
            a = res;
        }
    });​
});
```

Should do it? Did you need the ASP part?

Comment: I already tried that. When I put alert(a) below a = res I got good data, but when I put alert(a) after $.ajax({});​ I will get null

Comment: I edited my script, this should work since a is now at global scope.

Comment: Same thing :( inside $.ajax({}) everything is ok, but after it is constantly null. I don't know I will try tu put rest of code in success: function(res) {}

Comment: I found this that real problem is [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905298/jquery-storing-ajax-response-into-global-variable) is actually that var a = null; is not waiting for success: function(res)

Comment: AJAX calls are asynchronous (asynchronous javascript and xml). You can set it to Synchronous if you need to block the thread until success returns, but I wouldn't advise it.

If you need it to by synchronous, set async = false in the options of the ajax() call.

Comment: Tnx, actually that was problem. I didn't know that that is working that way.