# Why cant I get the result out of the jQuery AJAX

Tags: ajax, jquery

My function is very simple, and based on what I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905298/jquery-storing-ajax-response-into-global-variable). Yet I cant seem to make it work, whats wrong?

```
function ajax(url) {
    var result;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {
            result = data;
            //$('#test').html(data);
            }
        });
    return result;
    }
```

The function is getting the data, for if I uncomment the commented code and call it, then the data is shown inside the #test element. However, if I write

```
var test = ajax('my-url.php');
$('#test').html(test);
```

then it doesnt work. My guess is that for some reason, the data in "data" is not being stored in the variable "result". But I cant figure out why, nor how to solve it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `result` variable is not being changed until the AJAX call finishes, by which point the `ajax` function has already returned. This is the entire point of callbacks, the ability to schedule a task to be executed when an event is finished.

Javascript (in-browser) is inherently asynchronous.

Alternatively, you can pass in `async: false` to your `$.ajax` call and it will wait until it's finished, but reverting back to your original style makes more sense.

Edit: It looks like what you're doing can be accomplished with [`$.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Answer (score 1):

If you modify your `$.ajax` call to not execute asynchronously it will work as you expect:

```
function ajax(url) {
  var result;
  $.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
        result = data;
        //$('#test').html(data);
        }
    });
  return result;
}
```

The `$.ajax` function returns immediately and does not wait for the AJAX call to return.

Comment: Thanks, I chose the other answer because after some reading, I decided to use $.load()