# Get MySql data and store it into Javascript array

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

want to retrieve a records data from Mysql and store it into Javascript array for heatmap.js map data in this format :

```
var testData = {max: 46, data: [{lat: 33.5363, lon:-117.044, value: 1},{lat: 33.5608, lon:-117.24, value: 1},..]};
```

Now I get stuck at here, and I don't know how to connecting from Jquery into my `var testData = new Array();`, How I should do to solve this?

**(UPDATED CORRECT CODE)**

get_query.php

```
<?php
require_once('./db_con.php');
$dbcon=new db;


$query="SELECT (SELECT geo_lat FROM fun WHERE created_at <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1   minute) AS geo_lat," . 
       "(SELECT geo_long FROM fun WHERE created_at <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 minute) AS geo_long";

$result = mysqli_query($dbcon,$query);
$data = array(); 

    while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

     $data[] = array("lat"=>$row["geo_lat"], "lon"=>$row["geo_long"], "value"=>1); 
     $post_data = json_encode(array('max' => 46, 'data' => $data));
    }
    echo $post_data;
 ?>
```

my_data.js based from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3504020/2401630):

```
jQuery.extend({
getValues: function(url) {
    var result = null;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            result = JSON.stringify(data);
        }
    });
   return result;
}
});

var testData = $.getValues("get_query.php");
```

Thanks to Orangepill and Chrislondon.

Comment: whoot `while(true){`  ?

Comment: Why do you have `while(true){`?

Comment: `json_encode` should only be called once, at the very end, once the array is built the way you want it.

Comment: Are you trying to create a continuous feed of data?

Comment: sorry that wrong line, I was updated now.

Comment: @mathew, Nope, only for client request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your question is how to connect your jQuery to your `var data` so I won't get into the myriad of problems in your PHP code.  In your success function you can set the `var data` like so:

```
var data = new Array();

$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type:     "post",
        url:      "get_query.php",
        data:     $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: "json"
}).done(function(response) {
    data = response;
});
```

Comment: Hi Chris, how to tested this code, I has implemented with heatmap.js but it still not works.

Comment: I haven't used heatmap.js before but looking at their code try doing this: heatmap.store.setDataSet(response); inside of the done function.

Comment: it seems the code not work because the var data resulting double quotes in json data {"lat":"-6.92015","lon":"107.67024","value":1}. how I can remove that?

Comment: Hmm... maybe try this in your php: $data[] = array("lat"=>(float)$row["geo_lat"], "lon"=>(float)$row["geo_long"], "value"=>1)

Comment: Thanks, it work, but my json still don't store in javascript variable, it is need to be parse? I really confuse working with jquery-AJAX, I dont receive any data and error.

Comment: When you have `dataType: "json"` in your ajax parameters it automatically parses the response as JSON. If the response isn't being parsed then that probably means your ajax file is returning bad JSON.  If you're using Chrome you can open up the Network tab and view the response coming back from the Ajax file. Try pasting it into a JSON validator like: http://jsonlint.com/ and see if that helps

Answer (score 3):

```
while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbcon,$result)){
    $data[] = array("lat"=>$row["geo_lat"], "lon"=>$row["geo_long"], "value"=>1);
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

should get you what you are looking for. when building data for json_encode just use native php types instead of json, let json_encode take care of that

Comment: Thanks, when I executed the php script, the page result this '[]', are this correct? sorry for my lack of knowledges.

Comment: When I added 'echo $data;' at the end of code, I got 'PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1' and 'PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects exactly 1 parameter'.

Answer (score 0):

Your json seems incorrect:

```
var testData = {max: 46, data: [{lat: 33.5363, lon:-117.044, value: 1},{lat: 33.5608, lon:-117.24, value: 1},..]};
```

should be with quotes around the keys

```
var testData = {"max": 46, "data": [{"lat": 33.5363, "lon":-117.044, "value": 1},{"lat": 33.5608, "lon":-117.24, "value": 1},..]};
```

Since you use `json_encode()` in php I would assume PHP outputs this correctly. But maybe you are for now just working with a fixed (faulty) string for testing purposes?