# How can I get the data from MySQL database based on the selected ID using bootstrap and Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, mysqli

I have two php pages, the first php page contains the table which has the selection to which record will be edited using a Bootstrap Modal, the second php page process the data to update in MySQL database.

Here is the first php page (edit_account.php)

```
<?php
$cn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testdb");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblinfo";
$qry = mysqli_query($cn,$sql);
$nrows = mysqli_num_rows($qry);
if ($nrows > 0) {
    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($qry)) {
        $id = $rows['userid'];
        $fn = $rows['fullname'];
?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fn; ?></td>
            <td><a href = "#edit<?php echo $id; ?>" data-toggle = "modal" class = "btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>

        <div class = "modal" id = "edit<?php echo $id; ?>">
            <div class = "modal-dialog">
                <div class = "modal-content">
                    <div class = "modal-header">
                        <h5 class = "modal-title">Edit Information</h5>
                        <button class = "close" data-dismiss = "modal">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "modal-body">
                        <input type = "text" id = "user_id" value = "<?php echo $id; ?>" class = "form-control" />
                        <input type = "text" id = "full_name" value = "<?php echo $fn; ?>" class = "form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class = "modal-footer">
                        <button class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm" id = "update<?php echo $id; ?>">Update</button>
                        <button class = "btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-dismiss = "modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            $("#update<?php echo $id; ?>").click(function() {
                var id = $("#user_id").val();
                var fn = $("#full_name").val();
                if (confirm("Are you sure you want update this record?")) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "edit_account_process.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {
                            userid: id,
                            fullname: fn
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            $("#showData").html(data);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>                       
 <?php      

    }
}
 ?>
```

Second php page (edit_account_process.php): (This page will be use for updating records)

```
<?php
$cn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testdb");
$id = $_POST['userid'];
$fn = $_POST['fullname'];

//for Testing
echo $id . " " . $fn;

$sql = "UPDATE tblinfo SET fullname = '$fn' WHERE userid = '$id' ";
$result = mysqli_query($cn,$sql);

if ($result) {
    echo "<script>alert('Successfully updated!');</script>";
}
else {
    echo "<script>alert('Unable to update the record!');</script>";
}
?>
```

What's happening to my code now is that it always select the first record in my database even I tried to select other records. Here's the

[image: error image]

**How can I target the specific ID which will be updated?**

Thank you in advance

Comment: post your update query

Comment: @sid I already posted the update query

Comment: what is the primary key column name in your table?

Comment: @sid, primary key is "userid"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to define multiple modals, use multiple scripts - as you are now doing (inside the loop, you create a new modal, and a new script).

Instead, add *one* modal that you dynamically assign values to, and use *one* script that listens for clicks on the button. That click fetches the values you need from `data-*` attributes and puts them into the value of the input fields in your modal.

```
<?php
$cn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testdb");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblinfo";
$qry = mysqli_query($cn,$sql);
$nrows = mysqli_num_rows($qry);
if ($nrows > 0) {
    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($qry)) {
        $id = $rows['userid'];
        $fn = $rows['fullname'];
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fn; ?></td>
            <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm toggleEditModal" data-uid="<?php echo $id; ?>" data-fullname="<?php echo $fn; ?>">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>                  
        <?php      
    }
}
?>

<script>
    $(".toggleEditModal").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#user_id').val($(this).data('uid'));
        $('#full_name').val($(this).data('fullname'));
        $("#editModal").modal('show');
    });

    $("#updateUser").click(function() {
        var id = $("#user_id").val();
        var fn = $("#full_name").val();
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want update this record?")) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "edit_account_process.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    userid: id,
                    fullname: fn
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#showData").html(data);
                    $("#editModal").modal('hide');
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>     

<div class = "modal" id = "editModal">
    <div class = "modal-dialog">
        <div class = "modal-content">
            <div class = "modal-header">
                <h5 class = "modal-title">Edit Information</h5>
                <button class = "close" data-dismiss = "modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class = "modal-body">
                <input type = "text" id = "user_id" value = "" class = "form-control" />
                <input type = "text" id = "full_name" value = "" class = "form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class = "modal-footer">
                <button class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm" id = "updateUser">Update</button>
                <button class = "btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-dismiss = "modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, I tried your code above but the modal is not showing when I clicked the Edit button?

Comment: Did you use all of the code above, or just parts of it? `$("#editModal").modal('show');` should trigger the modal if you have included the Boostrap Javascript.

Comment: Yes I use the whole code above that you posted specially this part : $("#editModal").modal('show'); and Bootstrap Javascript were also included in my page

Comment: Hi its working now :) I just edited your code above, these parts: $('#user_id').val($(this).data('uid')): $('#full_name').val($(this).data('fullname')): I changed : (colon) to ; (semi-colon)

Comment: Thank you again :) Just one more question, what If I had few more fields in my database, will I just add another  data-xxx= "<?php echo $xxx; ?>" inside this tag <a></a>?

Comment: Ahh, slight typo there, whoops! I'll fix that. If you get a lot of other fields, it can get quite messy. But yes, you can do that. Alternatively you can store all the data in a JS array, or you can fetch the data when you load the modal (so you run a new async query when the modal opens).

Comment: Thank you again :) Truth is I have 6 fields in my database, I just used 2 fields above to shorten a bit the code, How can I do that JS array if you don't mind? Can you give me an example? Thanks again

Comment: You have to assign values into the JS array within the PHP loop. Then you can access the array based on the user ID in your JS, and fetch the data from there.

Comment: So inside the while loop I'll add this JS array: <script>var data_fields= ["$id", "$fn", "$email","$utype","$contact","$address"];</script> Thank you again

Comment: You have to append it to an array, but something along those lines, yes. Though be careful of quotes there, it can break your strings if the PHP strings contain `"`.

Comment: Is this one similar to this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16673389/get-mysql-data-and-store-it-into-javascript-array or I should just open another question about adding mysql data to JS array? Thanks again :)