# How to fetch data from the database into a javascript file and store it in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, codeigniter, get

I am building a currency converter app for my school project and at the moment I am trying to get data from the database into a `.js` file. The exact goal is to get data from the database and save it into an array within a `.js` file.

As far as I know there is no way to get data from the database directly into a JavaScript file, so I am trying to make use of JQuery and PHP combination as pointed out in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16673389/get-mysql-data-and-store-it-into-javascript-array).

I have a database called `'currencies'` which has six columns: `id, basecur1, basecur2, basecur3, basecur4, basecur5`.
`id` field is for user id, and `basecur_` fields are for storing user's prefered currencies and can only contain three characters of a currency code (like `USD` or `GBP`) or be empty. I need to get a **result looking like** `const array_name = ["EUR", "GBP", "USD"];`

**Please note** that I am using CodeIgniter PHP framework for back-end.

In this file `query.php` I am trying to create an array from the data fetched from the database and echo it:

```
<?php
$current_user = $this->session->user_id; 

$query = $this->db->get_where('currencies', array('id' => $current_user));
$row1 = $query->row();
$base_currencies = array($row1->basecur1, $row1->basecur2, $row1->basecur3, $row1->basecur4, $row1->basecur5);

$post_data = json_encode($base_currencies);
echo $post_data;
?>
```

Unfortunately, I don't have deep understanding of JavaScript, so I can't really say what's wrong with this JS code, which is taken from the thread mentioned above, but it doesn't really work for me:

```
jQuery.extend({
getValues: function(url) {
    var result = null;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            result = JSON.stringify(data);
        }
    });
   return result;
}
});

var array_name = $.getValues("query.php");
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: you are trying to save the results in a `.js` file? or was that a mistype as your code seems to show the opposite

Comment: I am trying to store the results in an array inside a ```.js``` file. Sorry, if the original description was unclear, I'll change it

Comment: where is your code to save it as a `.js` file? (tbh it should be saved as a `.json` file). are you sure you don't want to just *serve* a json response rather than *save* (an actual physical file) to disk?

Answer (score 1):

Because of these line you already have a valid json string:

```
$post_data = json_encode($base_currencies);
echo $post_data;
exit;
```

and since you already set the `dataType: 'json'` jquery will parse the result as a json string regardless of the header.

Thus:

```
success: function(data) {
        result = data;
    }
```

You can debug using `console.log` it is a valuable tool for learning and making sure you are getting what you want at various points in your code. As another user suggested, make sure you aren't getting any 404 errors in the console. `query.php` doesn't look like a valid CodeIgniter route.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not passing a valid url
try adding an error function to get some info:

```
var result = null;
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        result = data
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert(error);
    }
});
return result;
```

Update: Try to output the variable directly as alex has suggested

Comment: I am getting ```[object Object]``` message.

Answer (score 0):

In your php file.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

in your ajax function

```
success: function(response){
console.log(resposne)
}
```

see if you are getting anything