# how to save ajax call request data in a variable and show it?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    context: document.body
}).done(function() {
    //show data
});
```

how to save data from ajax request into a variable and then show it?
and how to show a message "loading..." while it is proccessing?

Comment: function(data) { ... }); ??

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905298/jquery-storing-ajax-response-into-global-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    context: document.body
}).done(function(data) { 
    alert(data);
});
```

**UPDATED:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    context: document.body
}).done(function(data) {
   $('#loading').hide();    
   // alert(data);
});
```

markup:

```
<div id='loading'></div>
```

Comment: thanks how to show a "loading..." message when a request is send ?

Answer (score 1):

For loading message, use beforeSend() in ajax.

```
  beforeSend : function () {
      $('body').html('Loading...');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this. In your function you can show loading div

```
function your_ajax() {
  $('#loading').show();
  $.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    context: document.body
    }).done(function(data) {
     $('#loading').hide();      
     alert(data);

  });
}
```

Please add this part in your html

```
<div id="loading" style="display:none;">Loading </div>
```

Comment: how to wrap this in a timeout request for example refresh every 5 sec?