# Error when storing variables for use in later functions

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables, firebase

I'm trying to set up user authentication with Firebase and Twitter. The code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/905324/1683992) works to a point:

```
var url = 'https://molovo-comments.firebaseio.com/';
var myDataRef = new Firebase(url);

var dataStore = (function(){
  var user = null;

  var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(myDataRef, function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
      // an error occurred while attempting login
      console.log(error);
    } else if (user) {
      // user authenticated with Firebase
      user = data;          
      console.log('User ID: ' + user.id + ', Provider: ' + user.provider);
    } else {
      // user is logged out
    }
  });

  return {
    getAuth : function() {
      if (auth) return auth;
        // else show some error that it isn't loaded yet;
    },
    getUser : function() {
      if (user) return user;
        // else show some error that it isn't loaded yet;
    }
  };
})();
```

I can access the auth variable using `dataStore.getAuth()` and user.id is logged to the console. Calling `dataStore.getAuth().login('twitter')` also works, and I'm redirected to the twitter login page.

But if I try to return the user id externally using `dataStore.getUser().id` I get a `cannot read property 'id' of undefined` error.

I think I'm probably just returning `user` in the wrong way, so if anyone could shed any light on the issue I'd very much appreciate it.

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to the answers from @BenjaminWarren and @SpinyNorman I've updated the code to use the correct variables as below:

```
var dataStore = (function(){
  var userObj = null;

  var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(myDataRef, function(error, user) {
    if (error) {
      // an error occurred while attempting login
      console.log(error);
    } else if (user) {
      // user authenticated with Firebase
      userObj = user;
      console.log('User ID: ' + userObj.id + ', Provider: ' + userObj.provider);
    } else {
      // user is logged out
    }
  });

  return {
    getUser : function() {
      if (userObj) return userObj;
      // else show some error that it isn't loaded yet;
    },
    getAuth : function() {
      if (auth) return auth;
      // else show some error that it isn't loaded yet;
    }
  }
})();

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  console.log(dataStore.getUser().id);
});
```

Console output looks like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined main.js:37
User ID: 222936694, Provider: twitter main.js:14
```

So `dataStore.getUser().id` is being logged before the auth object has been returned, and therefore is undefined. I've tried different setTimout values etc on the getUser() return but it's alsways returned before the `auth`

Cheers,

James

Comment: Looks ok to me, what's returned if you log: `dataStore.getUser()` ? an object? if so, does it have an `id` property?

Comment: dataStore.getUser() just logs as undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var url = 'https://molovo-comments.firebaseio.com/';
var myDataRef = new Firebase(url);

var dataStore = (function(){
  var user = null;

  var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(myDataRef, function(error, user) {
    if (error) {
      // an error occurred while attempting login
      console.log(error);
    } else if (user) {
      // user authenticated with Firebase
      console.log('User ID: ' + user.id + ', Provider: ' + user.provider);
    } else {
      // user is logged out
    }
  });

  return {
    getAuth : function() {
      if (auth) return auth;
        // else show some error that it isn't loaded yet;
    },
    getUser : function() {
      if (user) return user;
        // else show some error that it isn't loaded yet;
    }
  };
})();
```

Looking at a few other references, `function(error, user)` seems to be the common format. The way you had it looked like the `else if (user)` was always returning false because `data` was being passed instead of `user`.

Comment: Cheers, I picked that one up already, but it hasn't solved the issue. Running `console.log( dataStore.getUser().id )` logs the error `cannot get property...` before logging `user.id` and `user.provider` from within the auth function, so it seems as though user is being returned before it has been processed

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the current code would not log the user ID at all, since the `user` variable is never updated. It starts out as `null` and is only set in `(...) if(user) { user = data }`, which can never be reached. I think the line should say `} else if (data) {` instead:

```
var url = 'https://molovo-comments.firebaseio.com/';
var myDataRef = new Firebase(url);

var dataStore = (function(){
  var user = null;

  var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(myDataRef, function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
      // an error occurred while attempting login
      console.log(error);
    } else if (data) {
      // user authenticated with Firebase
      user = data;          
      console.log('User ID: ' + user.id + ', Provider: ' + user.provider);
    } else {
      // user is logged out
      console.log('Not logged in.');
      user = {id: null}; // for example.
    }
  });

  return {
    getAuth : function() {
      if (auth) return auth;
        // else show some error that it isn't loaded yet;
    },
    getUser : function() {
      if (user) return user;
        // else show some error that it isn't loaded yet;
    }
  };
})();
```

EDIT: as Benjamin Warren pointed out, this is probably caused by changing the name of the function argument from `user` to `data` to avoid collission with the previously defined `user` variable. I'm assuming the log function stopped working after changing the parameter name from `user` to `data` as well.

Comment: You are correct, and I'd already made that change, but now running `console.log( dataStore.getUser().id )` logs the error `cannot get property...` before logging `user.id` and `user.provider` from within the auth function, so it seems as though user is being returned before it has been processed

Comment: Maybe you can try putting an object in the user and logging when nobody is logged in yet? I included an example in the code. Also (I have to ask), are you in fact calling `dataStore.getAuth().login()` before calling `dataStore.getUser()`?