# use ajax response as flowplayer source using flowplayer().load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, flowplayer

I want to load a url to video through a ajax-response, and use this url in flowplayer using the [load-method](http://flowplayer.org/docs/api.html#load-method). Simplified version of my script:

```
jQuery(".player").flowplayer({}).click(function(){

   var video_url = jQuery.ajax({ type: 'GET',       
                                 url: "loadurl.php",
                                 success: function(data) { return data;}
                               }).responseText;

flowplayer().load([{ mp4: video_url }]);
```

The error message in my browsers console:
"HTTP "Content-Type" of "text/html" is not supported. Load of media resource XXX failed." (where XXX is the correct result, generated by my loadurl.php script). The URL is correct though, but the video windows shows "html5: video file not found".

Loading the video directly in the player, or using the playlist (as explained [here](http://demos.flowplayer.org/basics/js-setup.html)) works perfect.

Any help?

Comment: I used [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8680038/611450), is there a better alternative?

Comment: This doesn't work either, so I guess it's a flowplayer.load()-problem:

`jQuery(".player").flowplayer({}).click(function(){
var video_url = 'http://xxx'
flowplayer().load([{ mp4: video_url }]);`