# Assigning the value of a callback to a variable shorthand

Tags: javascript

Probably this question has been asked before, I did my "Google homeworks" without results (it's kind of difficult to ask this as a question).

I find myself doing this often with async callbacks:

```
var wow;
myFunction(function(something) {
    wow = something;
});
```

Is there a shorthand to assign the value contained in the callback function to a variable, like above?

I can't change the code of the `myFunction`.

Possible real case scenario (with Angular):

```
$http.get(url).success(function(res) {
   $scope.data = res;
}
```

Comment: you mean like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905298/jquery-storing-ajax-response-into-global-variable)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use a "setter" function like this:

```
function setter(name) {
  return function(result) {
    $scope[name] = result;
  }    
}
```

and then:

```
$http.get(url).success(setter("data"));
```

Note that this won't work with the first example: there's no way to dynamically assign a variable.

Comment: This will do. The only other possible way is to use a precompiler like Coffeescript, were you have the `->` function declaration shorthand