# how to use ajax response in attr of an element

Tags: jquery, ajax, attr

I have made my ajax request, which works great and get response with type POST(server side is PHP).
now i want to use it in the placeholder of an element with this code

```
function checkAvailability() {
    $("#loaderIcon").show();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo ADDR;?>inc/promotion_check_availability.php",
        data:'code='+$("#code").val(),
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data){
            $("#result").html(data);
            var result = $(data).filter('#result');
            $("#amount").attr("placeholder", result);
            $("#loaderIcon").hide();
        },
        error:function (){}
    });
};
```

but in the placeholder of an element shown [object Object]. i don't know what is the problem. i really appreciate if some one help me figuring out this problem.

Comment: what does this file returns `promotion_check_availability.php`

Comment: you should parse the result or return a specific the dataType

Comment: could you do console.log(data) to see what is in the object?

Comment: I consider your `promition_check_availabilit.php` is returning `text` then use `result.html()` or parse response to html first.

Comment: add `dataType: "json"` or `dataType:"text"` in ajax request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to answer my question. i search a lot in the stackoverflow and find this answer and work for me:

[JQuery - Storing ajax response into global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905298/jquery-storing-ajax-response-into-global-variable)

Answer (score 0):

try `$("#amount").attr("placeholder", result.html());` or `$("#amount").attr("placeholder", result.text());`