# Ajax is not working in Webix

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, webix

I am trying my first webix programm. I follow the get start document. As per the document I place my code in HTML page and two json file. Here is my complete code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../webix_v4.2.4_pro/codebase/webix.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="../webix_v4.2.4_pro/codebase/webix.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    #app_here {
      width: 1000px;
      height: 400px, margin: 200px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app_here"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "grid_data.json",
        success: function(result) {
          debugger;
        }
      });
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "tree_data.json",
        success: function(result) {
          debugger;
        }
      });
    });

    webix.ready(function() {
      webix.ui({
        container: "app_here",
        view: "layout",
        rows: [{
          type: "header",
          template: "My App!"
        }, {
          cols: [{
            view: "tree",
            id: "mytree",
            gravity: 0.3,
            select: true,
            data: tree_data
          }, {
            view: "resizer"
          }, {
            view: "datatable",
            id: "mydatatable",
            autoConfig: true,
            data: grid_data
          }]
        }]
      });
      $$("mytree").open(1);
      $$("mytree").open(2);
      $$("mydatatable").select(1);
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

My page is loading but one error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: tree_data is not defined

Also page is not oading. Am I missing anything in ajax or something. Can anybody please help me in this.

If you need I will place my json data also.

My tree_data.json

```
[
  { id: "1", 
    type: "folder", 
    value: "Music", 
    css:"folder_music", 
    data:[{
            id : 6,
            type: "folder", 
            value: "Music", 
        },{
            id : 3,
            type: "folder", 
            value: "Music", 
        },{
            id : 4,
            type: "folder", 
            value: "Music", 
        },{
            id : 5,
            type: "folder", 
            value: "Music", 
        }]
 },{ id: "2", 
    type: "folder", 
    value: "Music", 
    css:"folder_music", 
    data:[{
            id : 7,
            type: "folder", 
            value: "Music", 
        },{
            id : 8,
            type: "folder", 
            value: "Music", 
        },{
            id : 9,
            type: "folder", 
            value: "Music", 
        },{
            id : 10,
            type: "folder", 
            value: "Music", 
        }]
 }
]
```

My grid_data.json

```
[
  { id:1, title:"The Shawshank Redemption", year:1994, votes:678790, rating:9.2, rank:1},
  { id:2, title:"The Godfather", year:1994, votes:678790, rating:9.2, rank:1},
  { id:3, title:"The Godfather part : 2", year:1994, votes:678790, rating:9.2, rank:1},
  { id:4, title:"The good, the bad and the Ugly ", year:1994, votes:678790, rating:9.2, rank:1},
  { id:5, title:"My Fair Lady", year:1994, votes:678790, rating:9.2, rank:1},
  { id:6, title:"12 Angery Man", year:1994, votes:678790, rating:9.2, rank:1}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming `tree_data` is the `json` data you're trying to get with the `ajax` request. You need to return the data or store it somewhere for later use. In the code you have, you have not defined `tree_data` or `grid_data`. Try getting the data similar to how its done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905298/jquery-storing-ajax-response-into-global-variable):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.webix.com/edge/webix.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="http://cdn.webix.com/edge/webix.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="app_here"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var gridData = (function() {
      var grid_data;
      $.ajax({
        url: "grid_data.json",
        success: function(result) {
          grid_data = result;
          console.log(grid_data);
        }
      });

      return {
        getData: function() {
          if (grid_data) return grid_data;
        }
      }
    })();

    var treeData = (function() {
      var tree_data;
      $.ajax({
        url: "tree_data.json",
        success: function(result) {
          tree_data = result;
          console.log(tree_data);
        }
      });

      return {
        getData: function() {
          if (tree_data) return tree_data;
        }
      }
    })();

    webix.ready(function() {
      webix.ui({

        container: "app_here",
        view: "layout",
        rows: [{
          type: "header",
          template: "My App!"
        }, {
          cols: [{
            view: "tree",
            id: "mytree",
            gravity: 0.3,
            select: true,
            data: treeData.getData() // get your tree_data
          }, {
            view: "resizer"
          }, {
            view: "datatable",
            id: "mydatatable",
            autoConfig: true,
            data: gridData.getData() // get your grid_data
          }]
        }]

      });
      $$("mytree").open(1);
      $$("mytree").open(2);
      $$("mydatatable").select(1);
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

The `JSON` you have isn't loading because it isn't valid `json`; the keys need to be strings like this:

## tree_data

```
[{
  "id": "1",
  "type": "folder",
  "value": "Music",
  "css": "folder_music",
  "data": [{
    "id": 6,
    "type": "folder",
    "value": "Music"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "type": "folder",
    "value": "Music"
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "type": "folder",
    "value": "Music"
  }, {
    "id": 5,
    "type": "folder",
    "value": "Music"
  }]
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "type": "folder",
  "value": "Music",
  "css": "folder_music",
  "data": [{
    "id": 7,
    "type": "folder",
    "value": "Music"
  }, {
    "id": 8,
    "type": "folder",
    "value": "Music"
  }, {
    "id": 9,
    "type": "folder",
    "value": "Music"
  }, {
    "id": 10,
    "type": "folder",
    "value": "Music"
  }]
}]
```

## grid_data

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "The Shawshank Redemption",
  "year": 1994,
  "votes": 678790,
  "rating": 9.2,
  "rank": 1
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "title": "The Godfather",
  "year": 1994,
  "votes": 678790,
  "rating": 9.2,
  "rank": 1
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "title": "The Godfather part : 2",
  "year": 1994,
  "votes": 678790,
  "rating": 9.2,
  "rank": 1
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "title": "The good, the bad and the Ugly ",
  "year": 1994,
  "votes": 678790,
  "rating": 9.2,
  "rank": 1
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "title": "My Fair Lady",
  "year": 1994,
  "votes": 678790,
  "rating": 9.2,
  "rank": 1
}, {
  "id": 6,
  "title": "12 Angery Man",
  "year": 1994,
  "votes": 678790,
  "rating": 9.2,
  "rank": 1
}]
```

If this isn't the solution for you the problem you should look into is making sure you get the data `tree_data` and `grid_data` into the scope of your `webix.ready()`. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Jonthan When I am checking in network these url which passed in ajax itself is not loading. therefore I am getting error like "Uncaught TypeError: treeData.getData is not a function"

Comment: @shankysingh I updated the code I had a few typos in the last one, but whats the path to your `tree_data.json` ??

Comment: Thanks a ton. Now url is fetching in ajax. Grid is not loading but I will check whats cause that. I will accept this in sometime.

Comment: @Jonthan `tree_data.json` is in same folder where I place index.html

Comment: Don't know for some reason data is not loading.

Comment: @shankysingh can you add the json you're working with ? If you're running this on a server `tree_data.json` should load, the new issue should be with `webix` and what you're trying to accomplish with the `tree_data.json` data

Comment: I update my question. funny is when i am declear this in variable things are working. when loading by this method i am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$count' of undefined`  error

Comment: @shankysingh you had invalid `json` to start with, if you use update your `json` to how I mentioned in my answer you'll see the data you want is there  . Just `console.log` it in the `ajax` call so you can see that you have it. Now whatever it is that you want to do with that data that's another question entirely.

Comment: Thanks  a ton Jonthan. I know these are silly mistakes, but i make sure i come over from these mistakes. Thanks!! working